# Get the dropdown value and text from dynamic row to two textfield

Tags: javascript

How if i want get the value and text of the dropdown , and put it in the both textfield..
I only able to get the value, but not the dropdown text.. 
For example, after add row clicked, and dropdown clicked, the value and the text of the dropdown appears in the both textfield. Here is the code

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
            newcell.childNodes[0].id = "txt"+rowCount;
            break;
            case "checkbox":
            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
            break;
            case "select-one":
            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            break;
            }
        }
    }
    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {
            alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
            break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
            }
            }
        }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
        }
    }
    function addVal(obj,ob){
        var suf = ob.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        var txt = document.getElementById('txt'+suf);
        txt.value = obj;
    }
    </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
      <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" id="txt0" name="txt"/></TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" id="txtt0" name="txtt"/></TD>
        <TD>
          <SELECT name="country" onchange="addVal(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML,this)">
            <OPTION value="in">India</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="de">Germany</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="fr">France</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="us">United States</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="ch">Switzerland</OPTION>
          </SELECT>
        </TD>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JATry/1/)**

Change your `<select>` to:

```
<SELECT name="country" onchange="addVal(this)">
```

Change your addRow function to:

```
   function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
            if(i == 1)
            {
             newcell.childNodes[0].id = "txt"+rowCount;
            }
            else if(i==2)
            {
             newcell.childNodes[0].id = "txtt"+rowCount;
            }
            break;
            case "checkbox":
            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
            break;
            case "select-one":
            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Change your addVal function to:

```
function addVal(ob){
    var suf = ob.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var text = ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].text;
    var value = ob.value;

    document.getElementById("txt" + suf).value = text;
    document.getElementById("txtt" + suf).value = value
}
```

Comment: thank you.. it works... is there any other way rather than use getElementsByTagName("input")?

Comment: Your inputs don't have unique IDs, that's why I used `getElementsByTagName()`. In my example, I target the second and third inputs in the array, but you could loop through the elements and find the text inputs by name if you wanted to.

Comment: i think the problem is in here
case "text":
            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
            newcell.childNodes[0].id = "txt"+rowCount;

how do i fix this..

Comment: See my edits (updated code and demo). I have added a fix for your IDs so that you can now target them by ID instead of by tag name.

Comment: thank you very much :) i took me 2 days to finish this.. but you only took 2 second :)

Answer (score 0):

You are just passing the text of the selected option, not the value. If you just pass the dropdown object, ob, you can use that to get both parts:

```
function addVal(ob){
    var suf = ob.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var txt = document.getElementById('txt'+suf);
    txt.value = ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    var val = document.getElementById('txtt'+suf);
    val.value = ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].value;
}

<SELECT name="country" onchange="addVal(this)"></select>
```

You also need to tidy up addRow() so that the second textbox has a different id to the first so that your code can distinguish them. Having 2 elements with the same ID is technically invalid html (see Definition and usage in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)

Comment: it only work on the first row... once you add new row, the value is null

Comment: yes this is because your addRow() method is incorrect as I stated. It currently creates two textboxes with id txt1, not txt1 and txtt1